# How to take two binary numbers and operation from user and give answer

Tags: c, math, binary, decimal, operation

i am doing an assignment on c programming that operates(+,-,*,/) on two binary numbers for example if the user inputs 
: " 1001 + 1010 "
must add two binaries and give output "010011"

my code can only take each input step by step (takes first binary then second binary and choose operation(+,-,*,/) and then generate answer) and the generate the answer but the assignment argues to take the whole at once( 1001 + 1010 and give answer 010011 )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int num, num2, binary_val, binary_val2, decimal_val = 0, decimal_val2 = 0, base = 1, rem, base2 = 1, rem2, sum;
    char oprtr;

    printf("Enter the first binary number(1s and 0s) \n");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    binary_val = num;
    printf("Enter the second binary number(1s and 0s) \n");

    scanf("%d", &num2);
    binary_val2 = num2;

    printf("choose operation +,-,/,* \n");

    scanf("%char", &oprtr);

    while (num > 0)

    {

        rem = num % 10;

        decimal_val = decimal_val + rem * base;

        num = num / 10;

        base = base * 2;
    }
    while (num2 > 0)

    {

        rem2 = num2 % 10;

        decimal_val2 = decimal_val2 + rem2 * base2;

        num2 = num2 / 10;

        base2 = base2 * 2;
    }

    if (oprtr == '+')
    {
        sum = decimal_val + decimal_val2;
    }
    else if (oprtr == '*' || oprtr == 'x' || oprtr == 'X')
    {
        sum = decimal_val * decimal_val2;
    }
    else if (oprtr == '-')
    {
        sum = decimal_val * decimal_val2;
    }
    else if (oprtr == '/')
    {
        sum = decimal_val / (float)decimal_val2;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error");
    }

    int decimal_num, remainder, binary = 0;

    while (sum > 0)

    {

        remainder = num % 2;

        /*  To count no.of 1s */

        if (remainder == 1)

            binary = binary + remainder * base;

        sum = sum / 2;

        base = base * 10;
    }

    printf("The Binary number of the first one is = %d \n", binary_val);
    printf("The Binary number of the second one is  = %d \n", binary_val2);

    printf("Its decimal equivalent is = %d \n", decimal_val);
    printf("Its decimal equivalent is = %d \n", decimal_val2);

    printf("And their Value is = %d \n", sum);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to avoid using `scanf`. Read the input as a string, e.g. with `fgets`. Loop over your string character by character, skip whitespace, check and copy the digits of the 1st number to a new string, convert it to an integer using `atoi` (atoi is safe if you have checked the string), skip space, check and copy the operator, skip space, check and copy the 2nd number and convert to an integer. After 2nd number you should check that there is only whitespace and the line termination. This way you can find all errors in the user's input. Then you could use the same calculation as before.

Answer (score 0):

Before to read the operator you have to bypass the \n entered after the second number, so for instance `getchar(); oprtr = getchar();` rather than your `scanf`

you will always print value is 0 because you print sum rather than binary

you missed to reset base to 1 before the last while

additional notes

- to convert the two numbers from binary to decimal you written two times the same code, it is better to add a dedicated function
- it is simpler to ask to enter the num1{opr}num2 on one line, because after you just have to do one unique scanf : `scanf("%d%c%d", &num, &oprtr, &num2);`